# RegEx to check first two characters must be "1 (numaric)-" in 9 letter word remaing should be alphanumaric

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried coding in such way that code was not working

```
var redEx = /^1-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}/;

document.getElementById("rowidOpty").value.test(redEx)
```

Example: '1-5S6AW2R': in the string first letter should be numeric and
  second character must be  "-"  and remain alpha-numeric.

Comment: Add `$` anchor `/^1-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}$/` And SYNTAX ERROR `regex.test(value)`

Comment: *What* is not working, what's the input for which you get an unexpected result?

Comment: In this case :document.getElementById("rowidOpty").value.match(redEx)

Comment: Must it be 1 in the beginning or any numeric?

Comment: any numaric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `regexObj.test(string)` instead of `string.test(regexObj)`.

See [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for more information.

```js
console.log(/^1-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}/.test('1-5S6AW2R'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
pattern = /^[0-9]-(\w+)/g;

console.log('1-5S6AW2R'.match(pattern))
```

Try this pattern `^[0-9]-(\w+)`

**[Demo Regex](https://regex101.com/r/8j4UXP/2)**

Comment: `{1}` is usless ;-)

Comment: `\w` matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so it is not the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong function syntax:

```
regexp.test([str])
```

And the right one is:

```js
var regEx = /^1-[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}/;
var string = '1-5S6AW2R';

console.log(regEx.test(string));
```

Comment: In this case :document.getElementById("rowidOpty").value.match(redEx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the input matches exactly one numeric, one dash and 7 alphanumerics exactly, use this:

```
/^[0-9]-[a-zA-Z-0-9]{7}$/;
```

or if the first can be only the numeral 1:

```
/^1-[a-zA-Z-0-9]{7}$/;
```

If you want to search for all occurrences of this pattern in a string that contains a lot of text:

```
/(^|\s)[0-9]-[a-zA-Z-0-9]{7}(\s|$)/g;
```

```js
var restrictivePattern = /^[0-9]-[a-zA-Z-0-9]{7}$/;
var loosePattern = /(^|\s)[0-9]-[a-zA-Z-0-9]{7}(\s|$)/g;
var str = '1-A78Z2TE';
var longStr = 'We have 2 different codes 1-AYRJ3F4 and 4-23RJ3F4';

console.log("Validation of string to match pattern: ", str.match(restrictivePattern))
console.log("Multiple matches in string: ", longStr.match(loosePattern))
```